# External download manager for firefox and chrome

Tags: downloads, download-manager

Is there an external download manager for ubuntu 12.10 that will easily integrate with chrome and firefox and has pause and resume functionality and other features that kick ass?

I loved orbit download manager for windows and I am looking for something similar

Comment: Did you try the tool that I have suggested?

Comment: I gave up because I could not get things to work and I did not have the time.

Comment: if you used firefox install plugin downthemall, simple and works, don't know about chrome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a download manager based on `aria2`. It uses many connections and segments. Supports resuming download.

It is under development and from time to time a lot of changes occur.

[linuxdownloadmanager.com](http://linuxdownloadmanager.com/)

Comment: It's moved to http://ugetdm.com/

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be looking for flareGet:

> flareGet is a full featured, advanced, multi-threaded, multi-segment download manager and accelerator for Linux and Windows with full browser integration with all the browsers - firefox, chrome, opera etc.

Website: http://www.flareget.com/download
N.B: Its available for install in Ubuntu software center (old version).

Comment: It appears to be closed-source, with binaries for x86 and amd64, deb/rpm/tar.xz.  (and mac / windows).  They sell a license to unlock all the features.

Comment: @PeterCordes, That's right. But their free version is also pretty much useful.

Answer (score 2):

As told by Saji89, FlareGet would be an ideal choice for you as

> FlareGet is a full featured, multi-threaded and multi-segment download
>   manager and accelerator

But the free version in Ubuntu software center does not support "Browser integration", you need to pay $10 to get browser integration plugin. I guess without browser integration, download manager won't make sense.

So here is the workaround. I have tested it on Firefox 18 and it works like a charm.

> - Just go to Firefox > Tools > Add ons > Extensions.
> - Search for addon "FlashGot", install it and Restart the Firefox.
> - Go to Tools > Add ons > Extension > Preferences for FlashGot.
> - On General tab, choose FlareGet as download manager and check the check-box against "Show in Context Menu"
> - On FlashGot tab, choose FlareGet as download manager and check the check-box against "Show Toolbar button".
> - Now restart the Firefox. FlashGot will act as Firefox integration plugin for FlareGet.

Just right click any downloadable link and choose FlareGet. If you want you download video from YouTube just play the video, an icon will appear on right most side of the tile bar. Just click on that icon and FlareGet will capture and download the video.

I love Firefox so this is enough for me. Something similar can be worked out for Chrome.

> FlareGet + FlashGot on Ubuntu == Internet Download Manager/Orbit downloader on Windows

Answer (score 2):

uGet from http://ugetdm.com is the best download manager for Linux, is completely open source...has Firefox support right now via flashgot , opera support is coming soon and chrome support is in development right now.

uGet has everything flareget has and a lot more (except YouTube grabber) http://ugetdm.com/features

Comment: flareget very limited now in free version (2 x connection for larger files)

Comment: @saji89 the old links still work but you are correct in suggesting the new domain. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cant try these:

1. [FatRat](http://fatrat.dolezel.info/): http://fatrat.dolezel.info/
2. [jDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/): http://jdownloader.org/

Comment: JDownloader has special support for many file-upload sites, and it's GPLed.  Written in java, but hopefully not too much of a resource hog.

Answer (score 0):

for firefox i usualy use steadyflow. **flashgot + steadyflow** is good choice.

steadyflow can download in any streaming site and based on my experience, all of website that stream video can captured by steadyflow. I don't know it appear on other download manager or not,

for instalation

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sikon/steadyflow

i'm sorry if my english is bad.